# What are downsides to storing decimals as strings in proto3?

Tags: c#, persistence, protocol-buffers, currency, proto3

I am using Googles protocol buffer library within my persistent storage system and want to persist currency values, but I am not sure that the floating point types provided by photo (float/double) are good enough. Are there any downsides to storing all of my currency values as strings (e.g. storing "0.10" instead of 0.1), then using the Convert.ToDecimal function when I retrieve my data and need to do arithmetic?

Comment: representation differences

Comment: Also require much more memory to process than it should.

Answer (score 1):

You are **correct** in anticipating that `float/double` data types are **not** suitable for "currency!"

Consider how SQL databases *(and, uhh, `COBOL` programs ...)* commonly store "currency" values:   they use a **decimal** representation of some sort.   For instance, a true `COBOL` program might use a "binary-coded decimal (BCD)" data type.   A Microsoft Access database uses a "scaled integer": the dollars-and-cents value multiplied by 10,000, giving a *fixed(!)* "4 digits to the right of the decimal."

For the immediate purposes of this question, I would definitely store the values as strings, and then give *very* serious thought to the number of digits to be stored *and* just how to handle "rounding" to that number of digits.   (For instance, there are algorithms such as “banker’s rounding.”)

“Storage size?”   You **don’t** care about that.   What you **do** care about is, that if a particular customer *(or, auditor ...)* actually adds-up all the numbers on a printed statement, the bottom-line on that piece of paper will agree ... at the very(!) least, within a single penny.

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest, IBM's POWER CPUs have a decimal math coprocessor these days. Very handy for financial applications, gives a big speedup. And surprise surprise, IBM sell a lot of mainframes into the financial world!